# Laravel 5 Eloquent compare dates return 0 rows, DB::table returns rows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a problem with Laravel 5 and Eloquent, when i compare dates with a where clause on a model i have, called Callback, i get 0 rows returned.
If i do it with \DB:: instead, i get the correct rows returned.

```
    $callbacks = Auth::user()
        ->callbacks
        ->where('datetime', '>', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
        ->sortBy('datetime')
        ->values()
        ->take(10);

    $callbacks2 = \DB::table('callbacks')
        ->where('datetime', '>', Carbon::today())
        ->get();
```

The only difference i can see is that the first one, is done through an Eloquent Relationship, which returns a Laravel Collection of all callbacks for the authenticated user.

If i remove the `where` clause in the `$callbacks` expression, it returns all callbacks, ( old as new ofcourse, as there are no filtering being done then).

I have  tried with `Carbon\Carbon::today()` instead of the string literal i have pasted above, it gives same result, and the datetime in the database for one of  the callbacks is `2016-04-05 15:30:00`.

I have been frantically googling and trying all i could think of, and i really don't want to have to do a full extract of callbacks for a user, just to remove most of them in PHP before sending the ones for the day, to the view.

I know that i need to do another Where to avoid getting rows from the day after the day i'm looking for, I was just removing most of the chaining to clean it up :)

Any suggestions are very much welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Okneloper indicated, as soon as you use `->callbacks`, a collection is returned.  The trick is to keep this as a builder until you are finished with the query.

```
$callbacks = Auth::user()->callbacks()->where('datetime', '>', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')->orderBy('datetime')->take(10)->get();
```

Please note you also need to change `sortBy` to `orderBy` which is the correct method to sort on the `Builder` class.

Answer (score 2):

`Auth::user()->callbacks` is a collection, so you are calling where on the set of items in the collection. So the answer depends on the data you have in DB, but these will not produce same query.

I would assume the rows returned by `DB::` are not realted to the current user.

You can see what queries have been run by calling

`DB::enableQueryLog() // before the queried`

`dd(DB::getQueryLog() // after the queries have been run`

Comment: Currently the DB:: finds 2 callbacks ( all there is in the table ), and one of them is related to the current user, So the DB:: data is just 1 callback from another user on top of the Auth::user()->callbacks data

Comment: Looking at the API, the `Collection`'s `where` method is trying to match based on if the key and value equal each other.  There is no support for greater or less than. https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html  Would have to use the `filter` method instead of `where`.

Comment: @user3158900 That might very much be it! I'ma go do some tests!

Comment: You could probably just use `$callbacks = Auth::user()
        ->callbacks()
        ->where('datetime', '>', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
        ->sortBy('datetime')->take(10)->get()`

Comment: @user3158900 Almost working, you got me on the right track! I had t o put in a ->get() after the Where, since the SortBy doesn't work on Querybuilder, but with callbacks() the where() works as intended. Thanks a lot! please post it as an answer so i can accept it